# Facebook share button

Tags: php, facebook

I want that if person clicks the share button, there would appear the referal link in his wall. How can I do it? Because there is no such a thing like share in facebook like it was before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has deprecated its Share button in favor of the Like button. Check out the Facebook Like Button API at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - this will answer any and all of your questions.